# Switching from Microsoft Remote Desktop back to Mac

Tags: remote-desktop

I am using Microsoft Remote Desktop app to connect to a Windows machine from my mac. When I start the app it goes in full screen (I don't see any of the Mac controls). I was used to switching back from the app to the Mac desktop by using CMD-Tab but for some reason this stopped working. When I press CMD-Tab I'm getting a task bar of the Mac applications that are running but when I try press on an icon nothing happens - I am still stuck with the Microsoft Remote Desktop app. How can I get back to from that app to the Mac controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Remote Desktop automatically opens on another desktop space. You can quickly change between your remote session and the Mac desktop by pressing control + left arrow, and vise versa for going back to Windows.

You can also press control + up arrow to see all spaces at the top of the screen.

Comment: `control+arrows` saved me from having to ask a similar question.  It seems like this shortcut is really hard to find (it's not mentioned in the preferences for Screen Sharing, for example).  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try invoking show desktops <kbd>F3</kbd>

I have that programmed on one my mouse buttons.  No matter where I am, I can get to wherever I want with a simple mouse click.